Проблемы с записью данных из json в sqlite3 в Python
Недавно начал изучить с базы данных и их управление при помощи Python и столкнулся с проблемой. У меня есть некие данные в формате JSON
id_user={
    "123456": {
        "class": 11,
        "letter": "а",
        "name": "Jhon",
        "username": "jhon_123456"
    }
}

Я уже умею создавать простую базу данных и заполнять её
import sqlite3
data_base = sqlite3.connect('user_data.db')
curcor = data_base.cursor()
curcor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
users_data (class INTEGER NOT NULL, letter TEXT  NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL,
username TEXT NOT NULL)''')
data_base.commit()
data_base.close()

Я не могу создать такую структуру, которая отображала бы  мои данные JSON. Понимаю, что для этого нужно создать вторую базу данных со значением id (123456), но не имею представления как связать эти базы данных между собой. Буду благодарен, если поможете.

Для начала не нужна Вам вторая база данных, максимум нужна вторая таблица, но для ваших задач можно и в одной таблице все делать однако стоит добавить ID в эту таблицу и как я понимаю у Вас id_user это и есть "123456" а то как он у Вас сейчас используется это не верно (ID это число или хэш, но не объект) поэтому user={... и Id можно добавить к остальным данным где имя. Вторая таблица понадобится если у Вас в программе будут какие-то смежные данные с каждым пользователем.
